# QWebView set border visible

Tags: c++, qt, qwebview, qtstylesheets, qlayout

I want to make `QWebView` widget have borders in my layout and UI when running, similar to `QTableView`. Now it looks borderless and hidden.

Is it even possible?

Comment: Screenshot. what platform? Remember that Qt tries to look like OS you're running on. Did you check your code on other platforms?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set border to QWebView. Instead you can place your QWebView inside another QWidget and set it's border. See example below (QtDesigner):

Widgets hierarchy:

[image]

Look inside QtDesigner:

[image]

StyleSheet for QFrame:

```
QFrame
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: white;
}
```