# Add parent to UI Object in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwebview, qframe

I have QWebView object located on my UI in Designer Tab, I want to add a parent to him which will be QFrame, reason I am doing this is because I cannot use border QSS property on QWebView.

Comment: So add a frame to your window, set a layout to it and put the webview inside that layout. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: I want to display QWebView inside of QFrame.

Comment: Yes, but what is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I know that it can be done like this QWebView vw = new QWebView(&frame), but how to do this when we don't have QFrame frame = new QFrame; defined?

Comment: You need a `QFrame` object if you want to put `QWebView` inside a frame. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249403/qwebview-set-border-visible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the designer to build an .ui file, you can drag a QFrame onto the widget, and the QWebView onto the QFrame. That will set QFrame as QWebView's parent.